# Running Nginx outside docker container getting error when using custom domain

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running a docker container on port 5000. And I use nginx outside the container without using docker options. Now, it's fine when I access using IP but when I tried to access via my domain name I is not working. On some site I seen that when using I need to add root but, while using it's not an option right?

````
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http{
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my-instance-ip-here>;

    location / {
        root /;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
}```
````

Comment: Could you share nginx `access.log` to see if requests has reached the upstream service? Also what is the result of `nginx -t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh, your question is not so clear but I'm about to answer anyway to your question.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your-domain-name>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<host-ip>:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

You have to specify your domain name and, as service ip, host ip address (e.g. localhost:5000).

I suggest you to run also Nginx within a Docker container. In that case the nginx.conf became as follow:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your-domain-name>; // if the two services lie on the same virtual network

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<service-name>;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right running nginx within the container but adding SSL is a hard work so, i tried this method and works fine. The mistake i made was my domain didn't transfer properly. Thanks for your help, mate.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, is not difficult adding SSL. You have to generate certificates (using for example letsencrypt) for your domain(s), mount certificate folders into a docker volume and then use those certificates within Nginx. This is how I use Nginx basically everyday